# Jasmine jquery testing of a function with no parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery, jasmine, jasmine-jquery

I have a following function:

```
function prompt_mandatory_field_completion(){
    $("#mandatory_fail").show(150, function() {
        setTimeout(function() {
            $("#mandatory_fail").fadeOut(500)
        }, 2000);
        });
    window.scrollTo(0,0)
}
```

That I would like to test with jasmine but regardless to what I put in my spec file the test seems to pass.

The spec file contains the following code :

```
  it(' NEED TO FIX THAT FADE OUT Should prompt user to fill in mandatory questions via prompt_mandatory_field_completion function', function() {
    prompt_mandatory_field_completion();
    setTimeout(2000, function(){
      expect($('#mandatory_fail').css('display').toEqual('random thing'));
    });
```

In my SpecRunner.html I am using the following function that I run in before each test in this description block:

```
  function setupFixtures(){
    setFixtures('<div id="mandatory_fail" style="display:none;"></div>');
    prompt_mandatory_field_completion();
  };
```

Any idea how to make this into a meaningful test? I guess I have been staring at it way too long and poking it from all the directions.

Best,

Adam

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to write a functional test of asynchronous behavior.  You might have a lot better experience trying to use protractor for this sort of test.  It's tuned more toward asserting things that will *eventually* be true.

However, jasmine does have an asynchronous facility since about 2.0, known as `done()`, that will insist that all of the asynchronous code has run before the test passes or fails.

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass the `done` function to get asynchronous tests :

```
it(' NEED TO FIX THAT FADE OUT Should prompt user to fill in mandatory questions via prompt_mandatory_field_completion function', function(done) {
    prompt_mandatory_field_completion();
    setTimeout(2000, function(){
        expect($('#mandatory_fail').css('display').toEqual('random thing'));
        done();
    });
}, 3000);
```

You can also pass a timeout as a last parameter, depending on what you've set in your jasmine's settings.

Otherwise, Jasmine will consider this test to fail if its execution exceed its timeout.